# how to use like operator on Postgres SQL Jsonb field in EF Core

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework, linq

I have a field inside my dataSet from postgress = jsonField (type: Jsonb).

My dataset object looks something like this:

```
dataset:
{
id:"221dsfsedf-234mfidu-ndsufds89",
source: "xyz",
timestamp: "24/08/2022 13:00:00"
jsonField:
{
"a":"val4",
"b":"val5",
"c":"val6"
} 
},
{
id:"221dsfsedf-23728837hjhu-ndsufds89",
source: "xyz",
timestamp: "22/08/2022 13:00:00"
jsonField:
{
"a":"val7",
"b":"val2",
"c":"val9"
} 
},
{
id:"2564fsedf-234mfidu-ndh783839",
source: "xyz",
timestamp: "23/08/2022 13:00:00"
jsonField:
{
"a":"val9",
"b":"val21",
"c":"val34"
} 
}
```

To search any value from jsonField, I am using below given LinQ query, which is working fine.

```
  foreach (var key in fieldHeaders)
            {
                var searchQuery = "{\"" + key + "\": \"" + query + "\"}"; // e.g. query = val9
                set = dataSet.AsNoTracking();
                set = dataset.Where(s => EF.Functions.JsonContains(s.jsonField, searchQuery));

                if (set.Count() > 0) break;
            }
```

As in above code the jsonContains search only full query or keyword but nor able to search partial string or substring.

My PG-SQL query is as below:

```
    SELECT s.id, s.jsonField, s.source, s.timestamp
    FROM app.dataSet AS s
    WHERE s.jsonField @> '{"a":"val3"}'
```

I want to search partial string using like operator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `r.jsonField` in your LINQ code? Where did `r` come from? Does your PostgresSQL query use `like`?

Comment: @NetMage its s.jsonField. I have corrected now

Comment: Does your PostgresSQL query use `LIKE`?